# Rename files based on variables in python using os rename

Tags: python, variables, wget, file-rename

I'm trying to figure out how to rename a downloaded file from `NWZV1WB` to `HENRY`. Right now it downloads it as `NWZV1WB`  as wget sees it, I bet.

Important note : the files have always numbers at the end
`NWZV1WB-1.jpg`
`NWZV1WB-2.jpg`
`NWZV1WB-3.jpg`

My code looks like this : ([Henry yuan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9407479/henry-yuan) - helped me)

```
import wget
import os
import multiprocessing


def run_process(url, output_path):
    wget.download(url, out=output_path)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    cpus = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    max_pool_size = 4
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(cpus if cpus < max_pool_size else max_pool_size)
    base_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    prefix_list = ["NWZV1WB"]
    folder_name_list = ["HENRY"]  
    download_list = []
    name_list = list(range(1, 7))
    for index, prefix in enumerate(prefix_list):  # return index and item
        folder_name = folder_name_list[index]  # changed
        path = os.path.join(base_dir)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
        if not os.path.isdir(path):
            exit()
        for name in name_list:
            download_list.append(['https://example.com/{p}-{n}.jpg'.format(n=name, p=prefix), path])

    for url, path in download_list: 
        pool.apply_async(run_process, args=(url, path, ))
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do and give example input/output?

Comment: I want to change the downloaded files in `multiview_list`.  Currently I'm downloading files with the `prefix_list(US_Code)`. So for example currently the  file name looks like `NMZURPR-1.jpg` and downloads with the same name. I would like to be able to reaname this file with my `folder_name_list (EU_Code)` variable.

Comment: @user2653663 any thoughts ?

Comment: If you're saying "I have a list of filenames in `prefix_list`, and another list of filenames in `folder_name_list`, and I want to rename all the files in the first so they have the names in the second", you need something like `for old, new in zip(prefix_list, folder_name_list): os.rename(old, new)`. If that's _not_ what you're saying, please clarify further. A [mcve] would be of enormous help. (Preferably one that does not require multiprocessing or wget)

Comment: @Kevin Appreciate your help ! I think you're pretty close to solve my puzzle ! Question is where `for old, new in zip(prefix_list, folder_name_list): os.rename(old, new)` would go into my code ? Does it matter the location ?

Comment: Yes, the location matters. It has to go after whatever code creates the files in the first place, or else it won't be able to find those files to rename them. And you shouldn't put it before any code that accesses those files by their old names, since the files won't have those names after you rename them.

Comment: @Kevin, can you check my code, I updated it, it should be more clear now. Just try running it you'll see what I mean. It's easy but so difficult at the same time :(

Comment: @Henry yuan - can you have a look please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing, but with the comment thread I think I pieced together what you are trying to do. Currently your output is:

```
Old name:      New name:
NWZV1WB-1.jpg  NWZV1WB-1.jpg

Desired output is:
NWZV1WB-1.jpg  HENRY-1.jpg
```

Your new file name goes in the `path` variable in download list. Try this:

```
for name in name_list:
    path = 'your path'
    newfile = path + folder_name +'-{n}.jpg'.format(n=name)
    download_list.append(['https://example.com/{p}-{n}.jpg'.format(n=name, p=prefix), newfile])
```

Comment: I knew I was close !!! Maaan, I spent a week trying to figure this out !

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is in this line:

```
path = os.path.join(base_dir)
```

As you can see in the [source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/v2.7.3/Lib/posixpath.py#l60) when only one argument join method simply returns it (which is probably not what you wanted).

```
def join(a, *p):
    """Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded."""
    path = a
    for b in p:
        ...
    return path
```

[Cody](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10099181/cody) already provided you with an answer, I'll just make it a bit cleaner with Python 3.6+ [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/).

```
for name in name_list:
    file_path = os.path.join(base_dir, f'{folder_name}-{name}.jpg')
    download_list.append([f'https://example.com/{prefix}-{name}.jpg', file_path])
```

Comment: you know u're a genius don't you ?!  danke !